# Appending to a list of objects

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a list of complex objects (file connections) in R. 
There is a character vector with file names. I want to open each file with file() and store its connection object somewhere (to be able to close them later). The length of filenames vector is variable. What I'm trying to do is:

```
files <- c("file1", "file2", "file3") #just for example
f <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files))
{
  f<- append(f, file(files[i], open="wt"))
}
```

Unfortunately f becomes a list of integer and i can't run close() for its elements

I need it to stay a list of connection objects:

```
list(file("fname1"),file("fname2"),file("fname3"))
```

If you replace append() with list() under the loop it won't convert connections to integers, but that will be a list of list of list etc..

Comment: `files_connections <- lapply(files, function(f) file(f, open="wt"))` or `files_connections <- lapply(files, file, "wt")` or `files_connections <- lapply(files, file, open="wt")`

Comment: You could also do (not tested) `f[[i] <- file(files[i], open = "wt")`.

Comment: @DrDom, please consider adding your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not R-style to append items to the list iteratively. More correct to use `lapply` function which iterates through the given object, apply a user-defined function and returns list. There are three call which should give the same results (not tested).

```
files_connections <- lapply(files, function(f) file(f, open="wt"))
files_connections <- lapply(files, file, "wt")
files_connections <- lapply(files, file, open="wt")
```